# How to change HTML background using CSS, for Chrome 61?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was trying to change the page background to red using `<body style="background:red">hello`, but in Chrome 61 not the entire page became same shade of red, see the darker red square here:

[image: not the entire page is red]

How do I change the background of the entire page to the same shade of red in Chrome 61?

Secreenshot with dev tools:

[image: screenshot with dev tools]

Comment: Can't replicate with Chrome 61 on Win 10.

Comment: Please provide working example in JSFiddle.

Comment: The screenshot in the questions provides a working example (with the `data:text/html,<body style="background:red">` link on it) on Google Chrome 61, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce this with jsfiddle.net. In jsfiddle.net, the entire page background is red.

Comment: To the downvoter: How can I improve this question?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page in Dev tools?

Comment: It is not reproducable here with chrome 61 neither on win nor is os x. It is likely that is only related to your setup. Maybe an extension you have installed.

Comment: @Krusader: JSFiddle is an absolutely terrible environment to reproduce this in compared to a data URI.

Comment: I suspect this is either an extension issue or a driver issue with that arbitrarily sized solid red over the lighter shade of red. Even if Chrome was coloring the html and body elements differently, the body element takes up the full width and height of the viewport, not an arbitrary size, in quirks mode. What happens with `data:text/html,<body bgcolor="red">hello`?

Comment: @pts I don't see anything suspicious there. Could you try disabling adblocker there? Also, are you able to repro this in any other context? Local HTML file, JS Fiddle, Codepen?? Or with any other color? Or any element other than body?

Comment: Or how about putting more text in the body. Does it overflow out of the 255x255 block, does it wrap etc. Does changing the background to `html` change anything? PS can't reproduce with Chromium 57 under KDE.

Comment: FYI `data:text/html,<body bgcolor="blue">hello` with Adblock Plus disabled produces 2 shades of blue on my Chrome 61 on Ubuntu 14.04, in an incognito window. Local and remote HTML files are also broken. (Firefox is fine.)

Comment: @t.niese: Thank you for this tip. I've disabled all extensions, I'm using an incognito window, and it's still broken on Chrome 61.0.3163.100 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Do you have a user stylesheet? Is the lighter area some kind of overlay? Can you still click links and buttons in it?

Comment: @MrLister: Support for user style sheets has been removed in Chrome 33, so I can't possibly have one. There are no buttons or links in the lighter area on this page. Other pages (e.g. stackoverflow.com, gmail.com) work just fine, without any ligher areas appearing. I have no idea whether the lighter area is some kind of overlay, I don't know what an overlay is in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but have you tried using css?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Code here-->
</body>
```

Comment: Tried it, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like to be a bug in a specific installation on Chrome 61. I don't have that installed anymore, and the background is perfectly red in Chrome 66 (and some newer Chrome versions as weel) with `<body style="background:red">hello` and also with CSS.